To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path
I am getting this error when installing Solana.
I run this line in Ubuntu:
cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --force

The error I get:
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable 
`CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.

I dont know how to set variables. I only use Ubuntu rarely. If I cant do this then I can only use Solana playground.
